# Neo4j stuck on loading when executing any query and sysinfo not showing anything Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 and neo4j 3.4.9.

when I run

> sudo neo4j start

```
Active database: graph.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /var/lib/neo4j
  config:       /etc/neo4j
  logs:         /var/log/neo4j
  plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
  import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
  data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
  certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /var/run/neo4j
Neo4j is already running (pid 3760).
```

now when i open neo4j browser and try :sysinfo it returns empty and if I execute any query it gets stuck on loading [browser result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgAdn.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was installing it on Ubuntu 14.04 on Vmware Workstation and the installation seemed successful. When i tried to login to the database with the default credentials (username: neo4j and password: neo4j) I left the host address empty and it let me in.. Now when i tried logging in to the database on ubuntu 18.04 (again, on a virtual machine) it automatically filled the address field with 'bolt://localhost:####' and now it works seemlessly